# How to use KML file in Android Studio and mark the listed locations in Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, kml

KML file contains Name and Longitude/Latitude of certain locations.I have already created a Custom Map via Google Maps>Your Places>Create Map and set it to Public.

Please suggest a method to integrate it in Android App either locally or remotely via Url.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml), to add and remove your KML data to and from the map, call `addLayerToMap()` and `removeLayerFromMap()` respectively. To access properties in a KML object, call `getProperties()` on any Placemark, GroundOverlay, Document or Folder.

> To add a data layer to the map, first create an instance of the
>   `KmlLayer` class. There are two ways to instantiate a `KmlLayer`.
>
> To import and render a KML dataset from a local resource, you need:
>
> - A `GoogleMap` object where the layer is to be rendered.
> - A local resource file containing the KML data.
> - A Context object, which is required to open a local resource file.
>
> `KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile,
>   getApplicationContext());`
>
> To import and render a KML dataset from a local stream, you need:
>
> - A `GoogleMap` object where the layer is to be rendered.
> - An `InputStream` containing the KML data.
> - A `Context` object, which is required to open local resources.
>
> `KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), kmlInputStream,
>   getApplicationContext());`
>
> After you have created a `KmlLayer`, call `addLayerToMap()()` to add
>   the imported data onto the map.
>
> `layer.addLayerToMap();`

You can check the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/setup) and this [tutorial](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/).

Comment: I have already went through the above procedure.But whenever I add the line "KmlLayer layer......getApplicationContext())" in my Java, I get error in getMap() and R.raw.kmlFile as they are marked red.I have already added dependencies for compile.android.utils.0.4.Still can't figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue